# Chart Wont Show When I Run It?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart, layout-manager

I'm trying to make a simple pie chart appear on a jpanel in netbeans with JFreeChart and got this:

```
public void createPieChart()
{
    DefaultPieDataset myPie = new DefaultPieDataset();
    myPie.setValue("Apples",new Integer(12));
    myPie.setValue("Oranges",new Integer(23));
    myPie.setValue("Mangos",new Integer(7));
    myPie.setValue("Pears",new Integer(22));

    JFreeChart myChart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Damo's Fruit Sales", myPie,true,true,true);
    PiePlot3D pie3D = (PiePlot3D)myChart.getPlot();
    ChartPanel myPanel = new ChartPanel(myChart);

    lowerMain_PNL.removeAll();
    lowerMain_PNL.add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    lowerMain_PNL.revalidate();
}
```

I get no compiler errors and when it runs the window appears with the button, but when I press the button my pie chart doesn't appear. Anyone know what I could be missing?

Comment: Check the layout manager of `lowerMain_PNL`. If you are using netbeans gui builder then chances are that it's `GroupLayout`. Adding to that at run time is tricky. Change it to `BorderLayout` instead, since you are using `BorderLayout` constraints.

Comment: I set it to BorderLayout but still no joy. Im a bit new to using JFreeChart so I'm unsure what I might be missing. EDIT: actually I went back and checked your suggestion got it working. Thanks!

Comment: If you suspect that JFreeChart may cause problems, you can minimize the unknows by testing with a simpler component, such as `JLabel`, first to check if the dynamic adding of component works correctly. I suggested the layout manager since that's the usual culprit when using the form builder.

Comment: I don't think the problem is JFreeChart, but dynamically adding components.  Prove me wrong by dynamically adding a colored panel in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: If @kiheru doesn't post an answer, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Oh, I had not noticed the comment had changed. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the layout manager of `lowerMain_PNL`. Netbeans form designer uses `GroupLayout` by default, so unless you changed it, that's what you got. Adding to a container using `GroupLayout` at run time is tricky, especially if the component contains more than one subcomponent (And requires adding components to the *layout*, instead of using the usual `add()` methods).

Change it to `BorderLayout` instead, since you are using `BorderLayout` constraints.